# Elasticsearch aggregation and filters returning different sizes

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to know why my aggregation and filters return different values. I think that the same number of documents should be returned.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "dates": {
      "range": {
        "field": "created_at",
        "ranges": [
         {
           "from":"now-24y/y",
           "to":  "now-18y/y",
           "key": "18-24"
         },
         {
           "from":"now-25y/y",
           "to":  "now-34y/y",
           "key": "25-34"
         }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

My aggs returns:

```
{
"key": "18-24",
"from": 852076800000.0,
"from_as_string": "0/1/1997",
"to": 1041379200000.0,
"to_as_string": "0/1/2003",
"doc_count": 130
}
```

But when I filter by 18-24 the result is totally different totaling 157 documents:

```
"range": {
  "created_at": {
    "from": "now-24y/y",
    "to": "now-18y/y"
  }
}
```

Comment: Which ES version are you using?

Comment: 7.12 @JoeSorocin

Comment: That’s strange because from and to in range queries were deprecated in 0.9.4. Whats the exact query you’re using?